# When using eredis, should I use a singleton or per-process client?

Tags: erlang

I am building a simple websocket server in Erlang. I am using Redis as a backing store, and I am wondering whether I should create just one singleton client and share it among all the different Erlang processes (different process per connection) that get created, or whether I should open a new client everytime I need to check Redis, within each process.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to start with just single instance and then profile your app to find bottlenecks. Later on you can add https://github.com/devinus/poolboy to your project and use pool of eredis clients instead of single one. Client per process does not sound like a good idea, but if you not going to have lots of that processes you can go this way.

Comment: Thanks. I'm designing for 10K concurrent clients so I think I will use a single shared instance to start off and scale up with poolboy.